# C pthread_cond_broadcast seems to be broadcasting to all cond variables

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex

I have an array of structs. Each struct is as below.

```
struct thread_st
{
    pthread_t thr;

    int conn;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
};
```

conn indicates if the thread has work to do. It indicates a task if it is >=0 or to wait if it is -1.
If it reads a -1 it waits using the following loop for a broadcast before continuing I've removed a little of the error handling hence the else etc to shrink the block to whats needed

```
while (str->conn == -1) {
    else {
        if (pthread_cond_wait(&str->cond,&str->mutex)) {
            if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&str->mutex)) { }
            return NULL;
        }
        printf("here b3\n");
    }
}
```

Now, my issue is, when the cond variable is broadcast
   pthread_cond_broadcast(&thr->cond)
where thr is of the type thread_st above all of the threads print the "here b3" statement. For the sake of sanity I have tested using 
The thread_st array is created here (again error handling removed)

```
struct thread_st pool[TP_SIZE];
for (i = 0; i < TP_SIZE; i++) {
    pool[i].conn = -1;
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&pool[i].mutex,NULL)) { }
    if (pthread_cond_init(&pool[i].cond,NULL)) { }
    if (pthread_create(&(pool[i].thr), NULL,worker_thr_routine, pool)) { }
}
```

Any ideas? this is my first real attempt with cond and mutex variables so if i am being stupid please tell!

Thanks

**Update**
The threads ONLY respond to a broadcast on the condition variable located in the first struct in the array.

**Update 2**
Found it. It was me being an idiot. Where i called pthread create I passed the whole pool. I only meant to pass pool[i]

Comment: `while (str->conn == -1) { else {` is obviously not valid C code. What's left out?

Comment: By the way, your idiom for handling failure returns looks problematic...

Comment: there is an if there which checks a stop flag. In each of the empty sets of brackets there is a perror and return statement.
Im also about to update the post since further testing has given me more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the reference to the array `pool` to all the threads, so (I guess, as the code is missing in your OP) each thread refers to the array's frist element.

You might like to change the following line:

```
if (pthread_create(&(pool[i].thr), NULL,worker_thr_routine, pool))
```

to be:

```
if (pthread_create(&(pool[i].thr), NULL,worker_thr_routine, pool + i))
```

to pass the reference to the *current* thread specific entry of `pool` tho the thread function.